# Could not resolve dependency: npm ERR! @angular/service-worker@^15.2.2 from the root project. Conflicting peer dependency: @angular/core@15.2.7

Tags: node.js, angular, firebase-cloud-messaging, service-worker

I'm trying to create an Ionic PWA with Web Push Notifications.  I'm following this article:
https://devdactic.com/ionic-pwa-web-push

It calls for adding ng add @angular/pwa and it fails on the install:

```js
⠹ Installing packages (npm)...npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
   
npm ERR! Found: @angular/core@15.2.2
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/core
npm ERR!   @angular/core@"^15.2.2" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer @angular/core@"15.2.2" from @angular/common@15.2.2
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/common
npm ERR!     @angular/common@"^15.2.2" from the root project
npm ERR!     peer @angular/common@"15.2.2" from @angular/forms@15.2.2
npm ERR!     node_modules/@angular/forms
npm ERR!       @angular/forms@"^15.2.2" from the root project
npm ERR!       1 more (@ionic/angular)
npm ERR!     3 more (@angular/platform-browser, ...)
npm ERR!   7 more (@angular/compiler, @angular/forms, ...)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! @angular/service-worker@"^15.2.2" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: @angular/core@15.2.7
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/core
npm ERR!   peer @angular/core@"15.2.7" from @angular/service-worker@15.2.7
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/service-worker
npm ERR!     @angular/service-worker@"^15.2.2" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution
```

The only thing I've found on Stack regarding this issue is in reference to my Node version:
node -v
v16.13.2

Angular Version

Angular CLI: 15.2.2
Node: 16.13.2
Package Manager: npm 8.1.2
OS: darwin x64

Angular: 15.2.2
... cli, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router

### Package                         Version

@angular-devkit/architect       0.1502.2
@angular-devkit/build-angular   15.2.2
@angular-devkit/core            15.2.2
@angular-devkit/schematics      14.2.1
@angular/fire                   7.4.1
@angular/service-worker         
@schematics/angular             14.2.1
rxjs                            6.6.7
typescript                      4.9.5

I need the service worker in order to implement the web push notification from Firebase.

There's a version conflict that I haven't found a solution to yet.

I also found a solution on Stack that suggested using
ng add @angular/pwa --legacy-peer-deps

I get the following error using that cmd:
Schematic input does not validate against the Schema: {"legacyPeerDeps":true,"project":"app","target":"build"}
Errors:

Data path "" must NOT have additional properties(legacyPeerDeps).

Also tried npm cache clean --force
but got the following:
npm ERR! Your cache folder contains root-owned files, due to a bug in
npm ERR! previous versions of npm which has since been addressed.

Any help would be greatly appreciated